# Como fazer verificações de campos de formulário de forma correta

Tags: php

Possuo um `form`e nele tenho dois `checks`, eles estão definidos com esses nomes:
$checkFin e $checkDep, se algum desses checks estiverem marcados é obrigatório o preenchimento dos campos correspondentes a eles.
Fiz a validação mas a mesma está falhando e não sei se a forma que fiz é mais indicada ou até mesmo a forma correta, a verificação estou fazendo assim:

```
// FINANCIAMENTO
if (isset($checkFin)) {     
    if (empty($BancoFinanc)):
        $retorno = array('codigo' => 0, 'mensagem' => ' Opção Financiamento marcada, por favor preencha o banco!');
        echo json_encode($retorno);
        exit();
    endif;  
} 

// DEPÓSITO BANCÁRIO
if (isset($checkDep)) {     

    if (empty($BancoDepCta)):
        $retorno = array('codigo' => 0, 'mensagem' => ' Opção Depósito Bancário marcada, por favor preencha o Banco!');
        echo json_encode($retorno);
        exit();
    endif;  

    if (empty($Agencia)):
        $retorno = array('codigo' => 0, 'mensagem' => ' Opção Depósito Bancário marcada, por favor preencha a Agência!');
        echo json_encode($retorno);
        exit();
    endif;

    if (empty($ContaCorrent)):
        $retorno = array('codigo' => 0, 'mensagem' => ' Opção Depósito Bancário marcada, por favor preencha a ContaCorrent!');
        echo json_encode($retorno);
        exit();
    endif;

    if (empty($Correntista)):
        $retorno = array('codigo' => 0, 'mensagem' => ' Opção Depósito Bancário marcada, por favor preencha o Correntista!');
        echo json_encode($retorno);
        exit();
    endif;      

    if (empty($CPFCNPJ)):
        $retorno = array('codigo' => 0, 'mensagem' => ' Opção Depósito Bancário marcada, por favor informe CPF/CNPJ o banco!');
        echo json_encode($retorno);
        exit();
    endif;      
}
```

A falha que está ocorrendo é que ao marcar o segundo check $checkDep e não preencher nenhum campo correspondente a ele o script está me dando a mensagem do primeiro check.

Comment: Da um `print_r($_POST);` p ver o que vem.

Comment: Dica, se  as operações forem excludentes vc pode trocar o checkbox por um radio e já deixar um valor por padrão, isso garante que o valor da ação sempre será enviado, ai basta verificar se é deposito ou financiamento.

Comment: Olá @rray, obrigado pela dica, estranho que se recebo a variável $_POST['chkFinanciamento'] e atribuo a $checkFin a mesma fica 'null'.

Comment: Coloca o form na pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse caso se o primeiro check falhar você está fazendo o `Exit()`. No seu teste você marcou ele?

Se você quer todas as mensagens de erro ao mesmo tempo modifique seu código para algo assim:

```
// FINANCIAMENTO
$retorno = array();

if (isset($checkFin)) {     
    if (empty($BancoFinanc)):
        $retorno[] = array('codigo' => 0, 'mensagem' => ' Opção Financiamento marcada, por favor preencha o banco!');
        //echo json_encode($retorno);
        //exit();
    endif;  
} 

// DEPÓSITO BANCÁRIO
if (isset($checkDep)) {     

    if (empty($BancoDepCta)):
        $retorno = array('codigo' => 0, 'mensagem' => ' Opção Depósito Bancário marcada, por favor preencha o Banco!');
        //echo json_encode($retorno);
        //exit();
    endif;  
...

echo json_encode($retorno);
```

Comment: Obrigado @Celso Marigo Jr, sua dica ajudou muito na solução do problema, o meu insert estava falhando por que não estava tratando a condição do check vir sem valor, agora estou atribuindo valor a ele, se vem com valor 1 do form, segue o fluxo e grava no banco esse valor, se o valor vier "null" atribuo a ele 0 e gravo.
Ajudou bastante.